# Get the SQL used in query when using Eloquent independent of Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I use Eloquent ORM **without Laravel**. For diagnostic purposes I need to know the SQL that was used to execute a query.

The code is pretty simple:

```php
// $this->hmisUsers is a new instance of the Model representing the HmisUsers table.
$hmisModel = $this->hmisUsers;
$hmisUsers = $hmisModel->orderBy('UserName')->get();

// $hmisUsers is an Eloquent Collection object
// How do I get what SQL was executed with `get()`?
```

There is a method called `toSql()` but that doesn't exist on a model object or the resulting Eloquent collection object.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this:

```php
$hmisModel = $this->hmisUsers;

// Enable Eloquent's Query Log
$hmisModel->getConnection()->enableQueryLog();

// Execute the query
$hmisUsers = $hmisModel->orderBy('UserName')->get();

// Get the SQL statement used
$sql = $hmisModel->getConnection()->getQueryLog();

// Show the $sql array
dd($sql);
```

The first element in $sql will have something like:

`select * from HmisUsers where UserId = ? and deleted_at is not null order by UserName asc`